# How to half the speed with TimelineView?

Tags: swiftui

I have a working code for animation my image tall and short

```
TimelineView(.animation) { timeline in
    Image()
    .frame(width: 317, height: test(timeline))
}

 func test(_ timeline: TimelineViewDefaultContext) -> CGFloat {
    let now = timeline.date.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate
    let angle = Angle.degrees(now.remainder(dividingBy: 2) * 180)
    print(angle)
    let x = cos(angle.radians)
    return 398 + (x * 10)
}
```

It works pretty good by returning the height. But I want to keep the feel of the animation but half the speed. How can I do that?